# error happen everytime I tried to click on github repositories?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have clone a fork of GitHub on my computer. it's working fine but now it's give me error every time I click on that project (that I have used) I see this error:

[image: Error on GitHub cloned project]

What is going wrong with me and my GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

You could be in a [DETACHED HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) here.

You can check that by looking at the output of a `git branch` executed within your repo working tree.

The SO question "[github for windows crashing several times a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780095/github-for-windows-crashing-several-times-a-day)" contains instruction to recover (but backup your work in progress first, just in case).

- closing that pop-up, and clicking `Tools -> Open a Shell Here`.
- From the shell, you can run '`git reset --merge`' to undo the merge that caused GitHub for Windows to crash.
- From there, run '`git checkout master`' to switch from the detached HEAD.
- After that, run '`git pull`' in the shell to pull down any new changes. It will prompt you to fix any merge conflicts (which is what caused the app to crash).